# How do I upload an image to a specific directory in my Azure blob storage from my ASP.NET Core application?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage

I would like to upload an image to a specific subdirectory within my blob storage container and I'm not sure how to do it.  Having looked at the documentation I can see that, there is an overload on the `GetBlobs()` which allows you to specify a prefix but I can't see one for uploading.  Here is my method that handles this.

Upload location would be: uploads/car/17999/

**CarController.cs**

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Create(Car car)
{
    // Define the cancellation token.
    CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken token = source.Token;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _carService.InsertCar(car);

        int id = car.Id;
        string pathPrefix = "car/17999";
        string fileName = "car-image.jpg";
        string strContainerName = "uploads";

        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(accessKey);
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(strContainerName);

        //An example of how I would GET the blobs from a prefixed location, I don't know how to apply this to the upload part
        //var blobs = containerClient.GetBlobs(0, 0, pathPrefix);

        var blobs = containerClient.UploadBlob(fileName, car.ImageFile.OpenReadStream());
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }            
        return View(car);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try by changing your `fileName` and prepend the `pathPrefix` there. Something like:

```
string blobName = "car/17999/car-image.jpg";
containerClient.UploadBlob(blobName , car.ImageFile.OpenReadStream());
```

This should upload the image in `car/17999` virtual folder.

Other alternative would be to use [`BlockBlobClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blockblobclient?view=azure-dotnet) and use its [`Upload`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blockblobclient.upload?view=azure-dotnet) method:

```
var connectionString = "UseDevelopmentStorage=true";
var containerName = "uploads";
var blobName = "car/17999/car-image.jpg";
BlockBlobClient blockBlobClient = new BlockBlobClient(connectionString, containerName, blobName);
blockBlobClient.Upload(car.ImageFile.OpenReadStream());
```

Comment: Wow, I was really overthinking it then.  Having used the prefix in my code previously for fetching data, I thought the same had to be applied here.  Works fine both ways.

Comment: Yeah :). Basic idea is that Azure Blobs don't really have folders. Your blob's name is actually `car/17999/car-image.jpg`.